Write an extension method over StringBuilder.AppendLine with specific FormatProvider
Write an extension method over StringBuilder.AppendLine with specific FormatProvider.
In order to avoid using the code which always explicitly passes FormatProvider:
StringBuilder sb = new ();
var invariant = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
sb.AppendLine(invariant, $"Now: {DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}");

I decided to write an extension method, to be able change the code above to the next view:
StringBuilder sb = new ();
sb.AppendInvariantLine($"Now: {DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}");

but due to lack of understanding of interpolated string internal implementation, I was not able to do it.
My best attempt was:
public static StringBuilder AppendInvariantLine(
    this StringBuilder stringBuilder,
    ref StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler handler)
{
    return stringBuilder.AppendLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ref handler);
}

but it is even not callable, let alone correctness of the implementation.
The compiler error with this call
sb.AppendInvariantLine($"Now: {DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}")

is:

CS1615: Argument 3 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword


I bet "Now: {DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}" is a string

but it is $"Now: {DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}". The $ sign makes this an interpolated string, as far as I understand.
The AppendLine signature from the first example is (IFormatProvider? provider, [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("", "provider")] ref AppendInterpolatedStringHandler handler)

Based on @shingo answer beside, solved by adding a custom InterpolatedStringHandler that just wraps the original one from StringBuilder.
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public ref struct InvariantCultureAppendInterpolatedStringHandler(
    int literalLength,
    int formattedCount,
    StringBuilder stringBuilder)
{
    StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler _internalHandler
        = new(literalLength, formattedCount, stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public void AppendLiteral(string str)
        => _internalHandler.AppendLiteral(str);
    public void AppendFormatted(IFormattable value, string format)
        => _internalHandler.AppendFormatted(value, format);
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value)
        => _internalHandler.AppendFormatted<T>(value);
}

public static StringBuilder AppendInvariantLine(
    this StringBuilder stringBuilder,
    [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument(nameof(stringBuilder))]
    ref InvariantCultureAppendInterpolatedStringHandler handler)
{
    return stringBuilder.AppendLine();
}

That said, such a sugar method is not worth to be implemented.

Parameters of type AppendInterpolatedStringHandler need to be decorated with the InterpolatedStringHandlerArgumentAttribute attribute so that the compiler knows where the StringBuilder needed to construct this handler should come from.
public static StringBuilder AppendInvariantLine(
    this StringBuilder stringBuilder,
    [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument(nameof(stringBuilder))]
    ref StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler handler)
{
    return stringBuilder.AppendLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ref handler);
}


Update
Although the above method solves the OP's error, @3per points out that it does not use the specified culture to append strings. To solve this problem, it seems that I need to create a custom InterpolatedStringHandler. A simple implemention looks like:
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public ref struct InvariantCultureAppendInterpolatedStringHandler
    (int literalLength, int formattedCount, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
{
    public void AppendLiteral(string str) => stringBuilder.Append(str);
    public void AppendFormatted(IFormattable value, string format) =>
        stringBuilder.Append(value.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value) => stringBuilder.Append(value);
}

public static StringBuilder AppendInvariantLine(
    this StringBuilder stringBuilder,
    [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument(nameof(stringBuilder))]
    ref InvariantCultureAppendInterpolatedStringHandler handler)
{
    return stringBuilder.AppendLine();
}


It's compilable and even works, but it ignores the specified culture and uses the default one

You are right, thank you for pointing out this issue. I will update my answer later.

Thank you for your answer! However, there are two prons: 1) for arguments without a format it ignores the specified culture 2) it lacks a lot of performance improvements which the original handler have.
I've made a solution with a handler that just wraps the original one. It works for all arguments and has the same preformance I believe.
At the same time, I am not sure if I still want to use this sugar or not.
